# How to set angular pageIndex default as 1 in angular material?

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material, angular-pagination

My `pageIndex` in backend (legacy code) started with `1` and angular material `paginator.pageIndex` started with `0`. How to set `pageIndex` default value as `1` in angular material? If I initialize `pageIndex = 1`. It's doesn't work actually. If I change backend value as `0` working but will break other legacy paginator. Is there any way to achieve this?

Im using `angular 8` & `angular material 8.02`

**app.ts**

```js
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  listOrders() {
    merge(this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = true;
          return this.storeService.orders(this.paginator.pageSize, this.paginator.pageIndex);
        }),
        map((data) => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.resultsLength = data.max;
          return data.items;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          return observableOf([]);
        }),
      )
      .subscribe((data) => (this.data = data));
  }
```

**app.html**

```html
<mat-paginator
        [length]="resultsLength"
        [pageSize]="pageSize"></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: why simply don't pass to your service the pageIndex+1? `return this.storeService.orders(this.paginator.pageSize, this.paginator.pageIndex+1);`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
     this.paginator.pageIndex = 1;
    }, 0);
  }
```

Comment: I don't know this is a good practice, but this article shows this solution and explains why it works: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

Set `pageIndex` to `1`:

```
<mat-paginator
    [ngClass]="'paginator'"
    [length]="this.propertyCount"
    [pageIndex]="1"
    [pageSize]="this.pageSize"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
    (page)="updateTableResults($event)"
>
</mat-paginator>
```